# VBA PivotTable Filters

Tags: vba, excel

So I'm having some issues with my VBA and toggling a PivotTable filter. This is my code:

```
Sub Macro2()
Sheets("Report").Visible = True

Sheets("Report").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh

Sheets("Report").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("dwm").ClearAllFilters
Sheets("Report").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("dwm").CurrentPage = "1"

Sheets("Report").Activate
End Sub
```

I've tried using "1", 1, 1.0 and haven't had any luck. The error I get is:

"Application-defined or object-defined error"

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Record a macro and see what value do you get?

Comment: When I did that I got ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("dwm").CurrentPage = "1"

Comment: Oddly enough once I try to run the code the recorder created it gives me the same error.

Comment: Are you sure you get the error exactly on that line? Have you tried stepping through it?

Comment: Yeah, I'm stepping through it

Comment: It should work. May I see your file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64055/discussion-between-kyle-mac-and-siddharth-rout).

Comment: I dont see yo uin chat?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason Excel 2013 might have been the issue here. I managed to find a workaround should anyone else run into this issue. I used a loop which would let me edit visibility of the fields. Here was the solution:

```
Sub CreateReport()

Sheets("Report").Visible = True

Sheets("Report").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh

Sheets("Report").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("dwm").ClearAllFilters

Dim pi As PivotItem

    For Each pi In Sheets("Report").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("dwm").PivotItems
        If pi.Value = 0 Then

        pi.Visible = False

        End If

    Next pi

Sheets("Report").Activate

End Sub
```